# Save and load objects without breaking encapsulation

Tags: java, database, design-patterns, encapsulation, memento

I want to save and load objects to a database without using a ORM (like Hibernate).

Lets say i have the following class:

```
public class Person {
    private int age;

    public void birthday(){
        age++;
    }
 }
```

This class doesn't provide a get-method, so the internal state (age) is encapsulated.

If i want to save the object i need a getter method to do the following:

```
insert into TABLE_PERSON (id, age) vales (1, person.getAge());
```

The otherway round i need a setter-method to load the object:

```
int age = "Select age FROM Person";
person.setAge(age);
```

But i dont want to break the encapsulation (by implementating additional setter- and getter-methods) just to save and load objects.

Is there any possibility to do this? Maybe some kind of pattern (memento?) or best practise?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned Memento. There's a variant called [Snapshot](http://www.designpatterns.dk/java_patterns.html#snapshot) documented by Grand. Here's the UML class diagram:

[image: Snapshot pattern]

`Person` would be the `Originator` in the pattern.

You could dump the Memento instance to a binary object in the database.

Note that Memento is an inner class of Originator.  The createMemento/setMemento are a kind of single get/set which might be breaking encapsulation if you're a purist. However, the packet of information (the Memento) used on the call is an interface with *no methods*, so encapsulation of `Originator's` state is guaranteed. This might even work with an ORM if you map it properly.

Of course, **this seems a lot of work just to avoid a get/set.** Your Person/age example is not quite realistic (not a great model of a Person). It's quite normal to expose a person's age or date of birth, and exposing that property to persist the object would be OK. Encapsulation doesn't mean don't reveal anything. It means don't expose too much detail.

For example, let's not use `age` but rather `Person.birthday`. That could be stored internally as a String in YYYY-MM-DD format or using a Date object. Such detail would not be exposed (it would be encapsulated). This is also done so that you can change it and not affect clients of your class. Anything you hide can be changed without negatively affecting clients.

By exposing a person's birthday, you say *"I'm taking the risk that Person will always have a birthday."* That part is exposed and thus will be hard to change without breaking clients.

#### Edit after comments

Public methods (e.g., `save` and `load`) in `Person` can take care of the save/load database operation. They will have access to private fields (`age`) and can get the job done.  You said you're not using an ORM, so then you just do it yourself.

Comment: I agree with you that the the memento object is hiding the originator' state so that encapsulation is not broken. And i agree that i could save the memento object as a binary object in the database. There is just one last thing i would miss with this solution: I would like to execute SQL Queries on the objects stored in the database which wouldn't be possible because the objects are not mapped to a table-columns. I didn't pointed this out in my question, sorry for that.

Comment: `Select memento from person` would work, right @Aeon? Every object table would have a single column for the Memento.

Comment: Yes thats right, but i mean something else: I would like to execute statements like `Select Max(age) from person`.

Comment: If you need to know age for SQL queries, then why are you trying to hide it in the first place?

Comment: I try to hide age (or other attributes) from other java objects, because i want to ensure ecapsulation. I need to access the attributes via SQL to make different analyzes. The SQL Queries are "outside" the java-application.

Comment: The original memento pattern (as described by GOF) says that the memento does not expose the properties/data structures to other objects, therefore not making it suitable for saving to database columns. I guess what we're saying here is that it would, so that a repository implementation can save the properties to database columns. This does expose the internals of the object, however, the crucial thing for me is that is that *only the originator* can produce the memento/snapshot (because it's a private class of the originator), thus preventing state being set without going via public members.

Answer (score 2):

Allen Holub wrote a few articles on exactly that subject. He proposes a Builder and something he calls Reverse Builder pattern.

The way it would work in your case a Person would be responsible for generating a representation of itself. That is to say you define an PersonImporter and PersonExporter interfaces to move data into and out of the Person object. These classes are basically part of the Person design. So:

```
interface PersonImporter {

    public int getAge();

    public String getId();
}

interface PersonExporter {

    public void setDetails(String id, int age);

}

class Person {

    private int age;
    private String id;

    public Person(PersonImporter importer) {
        age = importer.getAge();
        id = importer.getId();
    }

    public void export(PersonExporter exporter) {
        exporter.setDetails(id, age);
    }

}
```

This doesn't eliminate getters and setters completely it is controlling it using interfaces.

[Holub's Article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072302/core-java/more-on-getters-and-setters.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think, may not be perfect.

Encapsulation is done for data hiding. Perhaps, you just don't want someone to set a wrong value to the `age` attribute.

Maybe you can introduces a wrapper class, which is used by external code and only that class is allowed to use your `Person` class.

If you create a file with `public` wrapper class lets say  `PersonWrapper`, that provides getter and setter for age. But these getter and setter can have your desired logic of validations such as what values can be set for `age`, who can etc. Within the same file, `Person` class may be defined as `private` but with plain getter and setters for `age` param. Your `PersonWrapper` should only use `Person` class getter and setter on some predefined conditions.

In this way you may be able to have a better encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

one way here is the use of mapper classes. Create a PersonMAP that map the class to table and and encapsulate all database operations in that class.

Answer (score -2):

I really don't see how using getters/setters is breaking encapsulation.  Getters and setters respect encapsulation.  In fact, they're a means to achieving it.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/120828/are-get-set-methods-a-violation-of-encapsulation

Comment: You downvote me and link me to a question for which the first line of the top answer agrees with me by saying "Getters and setters don't violate encapsulation, they provide it."?  Please explain.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't the one who down-voted? The link to that question shows your position to be controversial (read the comments on the top answer). Also read my comment on the question at the link.

Comment: In that case, my apologies for rushing to conclusions.  But I would appreciate if those who downvoted me would actually take the time to explain why.  For me, encapsulation is about only exposing data through controlled interfaces, and that's exactly what using getters and setters achieves.

Comment: Every time I got a downvote on stackoverflow, I took it as an opportunity to learn (open my mind and consider alternatives to my view). There are lots of comments in the discussion at the link I posted that should answer "why."

Comment: I'm perfectly willing to "open my mind" as you put it, and consider alternatives.  Looking at these comments, I don't see that I've said anything particularly outrageous.  It's hard to address an alternative point of view when I'm left guessing as to what that point of view might be.

Comment: One thing I should add.  When I talk about using getters and setters, I mean using them with your own code.  You know your own code, and you know how it should be exposed.  Adding getters and setters to other people's code rather than figuring out their existing interfaces is a different matter.

Comment: You need more reputation to take this to chat.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I don't frequently post on this site, so I'm not sure how best to continue this discussion.  SO is needlessly restrictive in this regard, in my opinion.

Comment: In my example i would need to implement getter for every single attribute of the Person class (lets imagine that it has much more than just "age"). So in my opinion the whole inner state of the object would be exposed to the outside.

Comment: If all the data needs to be exposed, then so be it.  But the point is that it should only be exposed **through** controlled interfaces (i.e. getters and setters).

Comment: I agree with you that if the data needs to be exposed than exposing it through controlled interfaces is the right way. The point is that the need/reason for exposing the data is "just" the persistence layer. So every object that needs to be saved must expose all data.

Comment: I don't see why there being a persistence layer involved in this case should make any difference.  Even if each individual attribute that you want to be saved needs to be exposed by means of an interface, which I'm not sure is even necessary, so what?  Still not sure how this is violating encapsulation.